# How to mock firebase cloud messaging under android with firebase-server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mocking, tdd

I'm currently trying to **mock firebase cloud messaging service** for an Android unit test and I'm using [firebase-server](https://github.com/urish/firebase-server), a web-socket emulator for firebase.

Normally, the AndroidStudio tool generates a `json` file based on your firebase client account info. The problem here is that I'm using firebase-server and I'm not sure what info I should change in the `json`, I've changed my API key for `1` as mentioned in [a firebase-server issue](https://github.com/urish/firebase-server/issues/113#issuecomment-350171600), but what should I do for app info and project info?

Here's an example of my `json` for `google-services`:

```javascript
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "************",
    "firebase_url": "************",
    "project_id": "***********",
    "storage_bucket": "***********"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "**********",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "ca.project.my"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "***********",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "app.ca.project.my",
            "certificate_hash": "***********"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "***********",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "1"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 2,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": [
            {
              "client_id": "************",
              "client_type": 2,
              "ios_info": {
                "bundle_id": "app.ca.project.my",
                "app_store_id": "********"
              }
            },
            {
              "client_id": "************",
              "client_type": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

How do I connect my app to the firebase mock, or how does it work.

I'm using a global installation of `firebase-server` to start the `firebase-server`

```bash
$ npm install firebase-server -g
$ firebase-server
```

Comment: _"app info",_ where's that?

Comment: I meant firebase id app info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to mock an Android app against `firebase-server`, but never had any success. I decided against using `firebase-server` entirely because it is not well-maintained (last commit was in November 2017) and probably won't always reflect an actual Firebase instance even if it is updated at some point. See my comment on your linked issue [here](https://github.com/urish/firebase-server/issues/113#issuecomment-356696275).